# Problem with partial method C# 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Do you know the answer to following question?

> Let us say, it MyMethod() is declared
> as partial method in MyPartialClass in
> MyPartialClass.cs. I have also
> provided body of MyMethod() in
> MyPartialClass in MyPartialClass2.cs.
> I use a problem without answer“Magic”
> code generator which has actually
> generated MyPartialClass.cs, let us
> say based on some DB schema. Some
> innocent guy changes schema for good
> and then runs “Magic”.
> MyPartialClass.cs is re-generated but
> with MyMethod2() instead of MyMethod()
> declaration. Think of me. I am
> thinking that I have implemented
> MyMethod() which is used by “Magic”
> but in reality, “Magic” is using
> MyMethod2(). C# compiler does not tell
> me that I have partial method
> implemented without any declaration
> and my implementation is not used at
> all!
>
> Any solution?

I think it is a problem without an answer.

**EDIT** I got an answer :-). I had a typo in my code and that is why compiler was not flagging error. Jon already has pointed that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get error CS0759. Test case:

```
partial class MyClass
{
    partial void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ow");
    }
}

partial class MyClass
{
    partial void MyMethod2();
}
```

Compilation results:

```
Test.cs(6,18): error CS0759: No defining declaration found for implementing 
declaration of partial method 'MyClass.MyMethod()'
```

Does that not do what you want it to?

Comment: Thanks Jon, sorry to put Q too fast. I had a typo in my code and that is why compiler was not flagging error.

Anyways, thanks for responding fast. SO rocks!

Comment: No problem. There's no surer way of finding the bug yourself than posting it publicly first ;)

Answer (score 2):

In short, no; that is the point of partial methods - the declaring code **doesn't** need to know whether an implementation is provided or not.

Of course - you could just not declare the partial method: consume it *assuming* it exists; if you don't provide it, the compiler will complain of a missing method.

There is a *hacky* way to check at runtime (with `partial` methods), which is to have the other half update a `ref` variable:

```
partial void Foo(ref chk);

partial void Foo(ref chk) { chk++;}
```

(and verify it changes) - but in general, partial methods are designed to not know if they are called.

Another approach is a base-class with an `abstract` method - then it is forced by the compiler to be implemented.

Comment: Although the declaring code doesn't know whether or not it's actually being implemented, the compiler *is* smart enough to know "that I have partial method implemented without any declaration".

Comment: Yes, I was focusing more on the other half of the problem.

Comment: Fortunately I suspect in this kind of case (the name of a partial method changing) you don't get one problem without the other, so it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

This is the whole purpose of partial methods. If the method is not implemented, it is removed without a trace, and without a warning.

One solution to this type of problem would be to use a double derived pattern in your code generation. This is used extensively by DSLTools and is quite powerful.

Write the following code by hand :

```
public class MyClassBase
{
    public abstract void MyMethod();
    //Put all other methods required by the class here.
}

public partial class MyClass : MyClassBase
{
   //This class is entirely empty! 
}
```

Generate the following code in magic.

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(){}
}
```

If someone fails to implememnt MyMythod() in the generated code, you will get a compiler error.